# Implementing jquery in rich fcaes 4 on jsf< h:datatable

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Implementing jquery in rich fcaes 4 on  jsf    < h:datatable.

here is my plug in include and java scrpt it is working on html page i want to implimen to it on h data table

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "sScrollY": 200,
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "sScrollXInner": "110%"
            } );
        } );
    </script>
```

...tr's and td's ...in my h data table

all i need to know how to use jquery to call the above function in rich faces or jsf

Comment: First you need to call 

    jQuery.noConflict();

if you are including your own jQuery files.

Second, use, jQuery instead of $

Comment: ok i will do that  and can u pls specy how to call the above function in the script need an explae with jquery tag plz

Comment: ok, please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is how it should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#example').dataTable( {
            "sScrollY": 200,
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "sScrollXInner": "110%"
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Of course you need to include jQuery files, example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i include the jquery files for  the baove script as follows i nrich faces 4   <sandbox:jQueryPlugin src="/ns/design/Richfaces/js/jquery.dataTables.js"/>  ok i wil locnvert to above format then and i will try thanks

Comment: Oh! my good ness it is working awesome help ,Thanks a Million.Laabidi Raissi